# Storing same class objects in both Neo4j and MongoDB ssing Spring Data

Tags: java, mongodb, neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-mongodb

The real issue is that both tools use @Id types while I can not create that kind of an object stored in both.

```
    class DataBaseClass { 
        @GraphId  @Field("graphId")
        Long    graphId;
        @Indexed(indexName = "mongodb", indexType = IndexType.FULLTEXT)
        @Id
        String  _id; //mongodb id
    }
```

Neo4j @GraphId extend @Id so there is no difference between the two,
at first I thought changing graphId type from Long to String will will do the trick but I get casting exception error.
I also tried to use mongodb @Field annotation with no differ resoults.
In my humble opinion this prevention is bug in the Spring Data framework, that could be spared from Neo4j if the data layer could accept String id with internal casting.
I think I got the issue covered but I would like to check if there is a way to do this after all.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to store the same domain entity in both databases. Just store the information that's best suited for each db in the the appropriate one.

Comment: Generally you are right, but for fast prototyping it may crucial since it save time to market. for other user cases it may be necessary like in case you have object that contains payload I would like to have as is in mongo while nullify payload at the graph level.